# probability data matrix based on portfolio change over period

Tags: r, probability, portfolio

I have a data frame of big panel data like this

```
Date        Firms   Portfolio
2007-02-01    A      1
2007-02-01    B      1
2007-02-01    C      2
2007-02-01    D      2
2007-02-01    E      3
2007-02-01    F      3

2007-03-01    C      1
2007-03-01    B      1
2007-03-01    A      2
2007-03-01    F      2
2007-03-01    E      3
2007-03-01    D      3
```

Here each period has a fixed number of portfolios ( three in the above example). Now I want to create a logical probability matrix like this.

```
            port1   port2   port3
port1        0.5    0.5      0
port2        0.5    0       0.5
port3        0      0.5     0.5
```

if you consider portfolio 1 of period 1, the combination was A and B. But in period 2 portfolio 1 have B and C meaning that 50% of the stocks (only B) remain in the portfolio 1 in the next period. other 50% of the stocks of portfolio 1 goes to portfolio 2 because stock A is in portfolio 2 in the period of 2007-03-01. The portfolio 3 have E and D in the second period (2007-03-01) meaning that there are no stocks comes from portfolio 1. So we assign port1-port3 cell 0. Similar way I like to assign probabilities in other two portfolios columns.

Now if this process continues for 100 periods, we will have 99 matrices like that. But I need one matrix which represents average values of that 99 matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
a <- data %>%

  # First get long-format listing of all Date-Firms shifts
  arrange(Date, Firms) %>%
  group_by(Firms) %>% 
  mutate(to = lead(Portfolio)) %>%
  rename(from = Portfolio) %>%
  ungroup() %>%

  # What share of that month's moves with that to & from?
  group_by(Date, from, to) %>%
  tally() %>%
  mutate(share = n / sum(n)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

The `a` table will hold all the probability matrices in "long" format, where each existing combination of `Date`, `to`, and `from` get a row. To get the average across all matrices (each of which is all the rows of `a` sharing one date), we can take the mean value for all to/from combinations.

```
a_summary <- a %>%
  group_by(from, to) %>%
  summarize(avg = mean(share, na.rm = T)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(from, avg, fill = 0)

> a_summary
# A tibble: 4 x 4
     to   `1`   `2`   `3`
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   0.5  0.75   0  
2     2   0.5  0      0.5
3     3   0    0.5    0.5
4    NA   1    1      1
```

---

Sample data (added third period):

```
data <- read.table(header = T, text = "
  Date        Firms   Portfolio
  2007-02-01    A      1
  2007-02-01    B      1
  2007-02-01    C      2
  2007-02-01    D      2
  2007-02-01    E      3
  2007-02-01    F      3

  2007-03-01    C      1
  2007-03-01    B      1
  2007-03-01    A      2
  2007-03-01    F      2
  2007-03-01    E      3
  2007-03-01    D      3

  2007-04-01    A      1
  2007-04-01    B      1
  2007-04-01    C      2
  2007-04-01    D      2
  2007-04-01    E      3
  2007-04-01    F      1")
```